# Rest Framework: more detail on detail page than on list page

Tags: django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a very simple ModelViewSet with a ModelSerializer that has a SerializerMethodField that is slow to compute.

```
class RasterViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = Raster
    serializer_class = RasterSerializer

class RasterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...fields...

    computed_info = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Raster
        fields = (...)

    def get_computed_info(self, object):
        # Lots of computation here.
```

Now my problem is that on the list page (mapped to say `/api/rasters/`), `get_computed_info` is called for all rasters.

I want the detail page to have the most essential fields for each raster, and the detail page for each raster to have all the available fields, including the slow ones.

It seems a very common pattern to me, to show only a subset of the detail fields on the list page, but I find it hard to search for a solution.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way that this can be done is by using two different serializers: one for the list view, and one for the detail view.

You can control what serializer is used on a view by overriding `get_serializer_class` and returning a different serializer depending on certain conditions. In your case, you probably want to test `view.action` to see if it is `create` (POST on a list) or `list` (GET on a list) and only return the list serializer in that case.

Alternatively you can use [the `DetailSerializerMixin`](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#detailserializermixin) provided by [drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions), which packages this functionality into a mixin that can be used on your viewset.